# gammaray.exe - System Error: The code execution cannot proceed because Qt5Widgetsd.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program my fix this problem

Tags: windows, qt

Having built [GammaRay](https://doc.qt.io/GammaRay/gammaray-install.html) from source code on Windows 10, I'm receiving these system errors while trying to run the `gammaray.exe` binary at `C:\Program Files (x86)\GammaRay\bin`:

> gammaray.exe - System Error: The code execution cannot proceed because Qt5Widgetsd.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program my fix this problem

The error is also thrown for `Qt5Cored.dll` and `Qt5Guid.dll`.

[image: Error message]

---

Using Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt, inspired by repository `Install.txt`, I ran these commands inside the [downloaded](https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/wiki/Getting-GammaRay#building) repository directory:

```
mkdir build
cd build
set Qt5Core_DIR=C:\Qt\Qt5.12.6\5.12.6\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5Core
echo %Qt5Core_DIR%
set Qt5_DIR=C:\Qt\Qt5.12.6\5.12.6\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5
echo %Qt5_DIR%
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" .. 
dir
nmake
nmake install
```

The last `nmake install` command needs administrative privileges.

#### Side Notes

1. I ran into [such an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34078124/3405291) while building, which is resolved by moving the repository directory to a shorter path like `C:\GammaRay\` and building from there.
2. I have to set `Qt5Core_DIR` and `Qt5_DIR` variables due to some CMake complaints similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38746635/3405291).

Comment: The error means that `Qt5Widgetsd.dll` cannot be found at **runtime**. Building the project with `cmake` is completely **unrelated** to the problem. What related is whether the directory with your QT dlls is listed in `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By @Tsyvarev help, the error got resolved by adding `C:\Qt\Qt5.12.6\5.12.6\msvc2017_64\bin` to path environment variable:

[image: PATH variable]